# Jquery: Get the class of a parent using a wild card

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="row side cards-row-1 cards-row">
    <a href="#" class="card cards-front"> Text </a>
</div>

<div class="row side cards-row-2 cards-row">
    <a href="#" class="card cards-front"> Text </a>
</div>

<div class="row side cards-row-3 cards-row">
    <a href="#" class="card cards-front"> Text </a>
</div>
```

I need to get the number value of cards-row when the user clicks on a link.

I thought the best way to do this would be to use the Jquery [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector and [wildcard](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector.

This is my Jquery code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";
        $('.cards-front').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.cards-row').removeClass('cards-expand');
            var classes = $(this).parent().attr("[class^=card-row-]");
            alert(classes);
            $(this).parent().addClass('cards-expand');
            $(this).insertAfter('<div class="cards-shadow"></div>');
        });

        $('.cards-back .close').click(function() {
            $('.cards-row').removeClass('cards-expand');
            $('.cards-shadow').remove();
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

I am using `alert classes` to check what number has been captured. 
However, instead of capturing a value it just says `undefined`

[I have a JS Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/nSzer/)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, if you want to retrieve the class name, you need to do:

```
var classes = $(this).parent().attr("class");
```

If you just want to get the number after `cards-row-` and not letter then you can use this regex:

```
var classes = $(this).parent().attr("class").match(/cards-row-(\d+)/);
```

But actually, you can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in this case:

```
var classes = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
```

Since `index()` value is 0-based so that you need to increase it by 1 to get the correct value

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSzer/2/)**

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. However, I don't understand: What does the +1 relate to? For example in "row side cards-row-1 cards-row", "cards-row-1" is the second value. So when you use +1 how does Jquery know how to select "cards-row-1" instead of "side"?

Comment: @big_smile This method does not select the class name but the `index` of your div.

Comment: NOTE that if your divs are not in the right order the number that you get will be wrong. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/nSzer/4/)

Comment: @Spokey Then I believe that no answer can cover every problems that could possibly happen :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var classes = $(this).parent().attr("class").
        match(/cards-row-(\d)/)[1];
```

See your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSzer/1/) edited.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to strip the letters and leave only the number

```
var classes = $(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\d+/g);
```